# Spark job on Kubernetes Under Resource Starvation Wait Indefinitely For SPARK_MIN_EXECUTORS

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am using Spark 3.0.1 and working on a project spark deployment on Kubernetes where Kubernetes acting cluster manager for spark job and spark submits the job using client mode. In case Cluster does not have sufficient resource (CPU/ Memory ) for minimum number of executors , the executors goes in Pending State for indefinite time until the resource gets free.

Suppose, Cluster Configurations are:

```
total Memory=204Gi
used Memory=200Gi
free memory= 4Gi
SPARK.EXECUTOR.MEMORY=10G
SPARK.DYNAMICALLOCTION.MINEXECUTORS=4
SPARK.DYNAMICALLOCATION.MAXEXECUTORS=8
```

Here job should not be submitted as executors allocated are less than MIN_EXECUTORS.

How can driver abort the job in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly would like to mention that, spark dynamic allocation not supported for kubernetes yet(as of version 3.0.1), its in pipeline for future release [Link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#future-work)

while for the requirement you have posted, you could address by running a resource monitor code snippet before the job initialized and terminate the initialization pod itself with error.

if you want to run this from CLI you could use `kubectl describe nodes`/ kube-capacity utility to monitor the resources